# HTML5/CSS3 - Depth alternative other then only z-index?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, css, 3d

I'm trying to build 3D objects in web page using 2D images.
My tools are html5,css3 and javascript (Jquery).

The goal is to make a 3D illusion...
I can make some illusions by new css3 features and jquery animation
but the last piece is missing is the depth...

Is anybody have ideas how can I achieve that?

(The goal is to create 3D bouquet)

Comment: Can you explain you problem more clearly, maybe adding some visual aids?

Comment: Think about dragging 2D flower images into a bouquet. But since its 2D the view is from "aside"...after you dragged some images and created a  bouquet I want to give a ability to rotate the whole thing like it's 3D...(with limitation angles)

Comment: You should be able to do it with transform() in CSS3, but it would require a lot of work, be extremely slow and be a browser compatibility nightmare. To do 3D you should use canvas/webgl and a library on top of that.

Comment: I already checked the libraries like Three.js and WebGl...there are two problems 1) a lack of documentation 2) is like you said,browser compatibility...from the things I checked,webGL is a problem as well

Comment: Thing is, doing it "by yourself" is gonna be even less compatible, since CSS3 is still too varied (and that's ignoring people using IE8-). Doing 3D stuff in browsers is an age-long problem that has never had a definitive solution (canvas is the best you can get as of now).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check with [Introduction to WebGL](http://gdd11-webgl.appspot.com/#1).

[Example](http://gdd11-webgl.appspot.com/#9) what you can do